# Uso di preposizioni col verbo cimentarsi

Tags: word-usage, grammar, prepositions

So che ci si può cimentare in un'attività, o con qualcosa. Ma è anche possibile cimentarsi a (!) qualcosa?

Per esempio: sarebbe corretto dire 'Io mi cimento a porre domande su StackExchange?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Che io sappia, cimentarsi richiede o l'oggetto diretto o le preposizioni "con" e "in" nella forma riflessiva. Il Treccani offre questi esempi:

Cimentare la vita (nel senso di rischiare);
Cimentarsi in un'impresa rischiosa;
Cimentarsi in una ricerca;
Cimentarsi con qualcuno (nel senso di affrontare qualcuno).

[Cimentare su Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cimentare/)

Comment: Penso che _cimentare la vita_ suoni decisamente desueto, al giorno d'oggi. Personalmente mi fido poco del Treccani.

Comment: Dunque, si potrebbe dire "cimentarsi nel porre domande su StackExchange"?

Comment: L'attivo di cimentare è un caduto po' in disuso. Mi riferivo specificamente al riflessivo.

Comment: @WalterTross: Non sono sicuro di capire il tuo commento: un dizionario deve registrare anche gli usi passati, no? Deve servire anche a leggere testi di secoli andati.

Comment: @DaG, giusto, ma se rileggi la voce in questione, dice "oggi è vivo solo in senso fig.", e poi fornisce gli esempi "c. la vita, l'onore, la propria reputazione". Possibile mai che quest'uso di _cimentare_, vivo secondo il Treccani, io non l'abbia incontrato in 53 anni?

Comment: @charo sì, si può dire.

Comment: @DaG, mi rispondo da solo: è possibile, è possibile... Anche lo Zingarelli, più terra-terra del Treccani, riporta lo stesso uso. Riguardo il Treccani ricordo però di avere avuto più di una esperienza negativa.

Comment: @WalterTross: Che tipo di esperienze negative? Per me è un punto di riferimento, molto più ricco di accezioni, esempi, distinzioni dello Zingarelli, a cui pure sono abbonato e di cui sono soddisfatto.

Comment: Il verbo cimentarsi è caduto principalmente in disuso. Si usa quasi solamente nei costrutti iperbolici come "Mi sto cimentando in questa impresa", che è passato da una semplice frase ad un'iperbole.